# Large .git file size causing decrease in performance?

Tags: javascript

The size of a folder holding all my contents is 35mb while everything inside added up should be less than 2mb at max.  This is slowing down my javascript and causing my browser to crash when I load up my webpage.

My biggest are audio files that add up to 836kbs.

Why is my root folder 17 times bigger?

[image]

Comment: Can't resist asking. What else is in the folder? *What* folder? (In other words, need more details here).

Comment: Just added the files in screenshots inside of typing it all out. The gemfiles, readme, and config are all 4kbs.

Comment: `du -h /path /to/this/folder`

Comment: @Michael Great insight! Turns out that a ton of .git files are stored that aren't displaying. I probably need to remove some of those files and clean it.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask how those .git files are slowing down your JavaScript.

Comment: @Hamish The git files were 32Mb out of the total 33Mb. Will be digging deeper.

Comment: yes, but why some .git files in your file system should effect client side javascript performance is troubling.

Comment: @Hamish .git affecting my javascript was an assumption.  My javascript was fine, but as of late it's been causing my browser to crash at times.  My CPU overheats. Had this problem before and it was due to a large audio file.  Reduced it and the page ran fine.  I speculate that many many changes of the audio file and pushes have caused the file to build up with .git files, thus slowing down performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further inspection, it turns out that my root file is populated with .git files. Had to remove all those to improve webpage performance.